# ECC RAM Data Width showing 72

Tags: windows-10, memory, windows-server-2012, ecc

I have installed ECC RAM and I would like to know why Data Width is showing 72 instead of 64? I have googled but can't find any related answer at all.

Thank you in advance.

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1387]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\User>wmic MEMORYCHIP get DataWidth,TotalWidth
DataWidth  TotalWidth
72         72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ecc, so each byte consists of 9 bits, so 8 * 9 = 72. The extra bit is to compute parity. Some have more than one bit. It is in the wikipedia entry.

Comment: But I have another system with ECC ram too but DataWidth is showing 64. May I know why there is such a discrepancy? 

I have swapped the ECC RAM between the 2 systems and the returning result is the same.

Thank you again.

Comment: Read the wikipedia entry, there are lots of ways to handle ecc.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory

I could not find anything regarding DataWidth in the wikipedia entry,

Comment: Ignore `DataWidth`, Under `Solutions`:`This problem can be mitigated by using DRAM modules that include extra memory bits and memory controllers that exploit these bits. These extra bits are used to record parity or to use an error-correcting code (ECC). Parity allows the detection of all single-bit errors (actually, any odd number of wrong bits). The most-common error correcting code, a single-error correction and double-error detection (SECDED) Hamming code, allows a single-bit error to be corrected and (in the usual configuration, with an extra parity bit) double-bit errors to be detected`